# How TO Get Last Inserted ROW SQL (Not ID) Jooq

Tags: sql, kotlin, jooq

I am using jOOQ as SQL generator. I could see I am able to get last inserted row using `DSLContext.lastID()`. But how do I get underlying db sql string.

ex: For Sqlite `SELECT last_insert_rowid()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't any such specific query that you can get from the jOOQ API, short of constructing it yourself, e.g. by using plain SQL:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .select(field("last_insert_rowid()", SQLDataType.INTEGER));
```